# Automatic width of a column in a two column layout

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I have the following markup, which should not be changed.

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="name">name</div>
   <div class="label">label</div>
   <div class="value">value value value</div>
</div>
```

My question is how do I get a two column layout in which the first column consists of name and label and the second one consists of value. **Important is that the first column has an automatic width, so that it fills the remaing space. The second column should never be wider than the content or the maximum width.**

With the following CSS I can get the basically layout.

```
.item {
  background : red;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 9em;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 16em;
}
.name, .label {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 65%;
}
.value {
  overflow: auto;
  max-width: 35%;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

But how do I realize the automatic width issue?

See also my update here https://jsfiddle.net/qrrrv0jj/5/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using float instead of the flexbox model may be an appropriate solution. It keeps the markup almost as desired and just repositionate the value element.

```
<div class="item">
   <div class="value">value value value</div>
   <div class="name">name</div>
   <div class="label">label</div>
</div>
```

---

```
.item {
  background: red;
  height: 9em;
  width: 16em;
}
.name, .label {
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
  height: 50%;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.value {
  align-items: center;
  background: aquamarine;
  display: flex;
  float: right;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 35%;
}
```

See the example at https://jsfiddle.net/qrrrv0jj/6/.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it two way using `display property`. For old browse `display: table;` and for new browser `display: flex;`. Bellow is the example of old and new browser.

For old browser:

```
<div class="item2">
    <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="labels">label</div>
    <div class="value">value value value</div>
```

```
.item2 {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item2 div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.item2 div.name {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

.item2 div.labels {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.item2 div.value {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

For new browser:

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="labels">label</div>
    <div class="value">value value value</div>
</div>

.item {
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 500px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 500px;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item div.name {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

.item div.labels {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
}

.item div.value {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*:after,
*:before{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  -webkit-box-align: stretch;
  -webkit-align-items: stretch;
  -moz-box-align: stretch;
  -ms-flex-align: stretch;
  align-items: stretch;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #ffffff;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 500px;
  -moz-box-flex: 0;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 500px;
  flex: 0 0 500px;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -moz-box-orient: horizontal;
  -moz-box-direction: normal;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: start;
  -webkit-justify-content: flex-start;
  -moz-box-pack: start;
  -ms-flex-pack: start;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  max-width: 500px;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item div {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -moz-box-flex: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  padding: 10px;
}

.item div.name {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

.item div.labels {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.item div.value {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  flex: 0 0 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.item2 {
  background-color: #cccccc;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item2 div {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 10px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.item2 div.name {
  background-color: #ff0;
  color: #000;
}

.item2 div.labels {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 100px;
}

.item2 div.value {
  background-color: #ff0000;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="labels"><h1>For New browser</h1></div>
    <div class="value">value value value</div>
</div>
<div class="item2">
    <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.</div>
    <div class="labels"><h1>For Old browser</h1></div>
    <div class="value">value value value</div>
</div>
```

Note: If you use `flexbox` then you will not find any issue in last two column `width`. `display: table-cell;` will taking width until one single word isn't complete.

**EDITED**

I seen your Fiddle. I understand what your want actually. `flexbox` will not help about this issue. You need change your `html` structure. you can try this.

**HTML**

```
<div class="item">
    <div class="child-item1">
        <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply</div>
        <div class="value">value value value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-item2">
        label
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.item {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item .child-item1,
.item .child-item2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item .child-item1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.item .child-item1 .name,
.item .child-item1 .value {
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.item .child-item1 .name {
  background-color: #ff0685;
}

.item .child-item1 .value {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.item .child-item2 {
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.item {
  background-color: #ff00ff;
  display: table;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 500px;
}

.item .child-item1,
.item .child-item2 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item .child-item1 {
  width: -webkit-calc(100% - 200px);
  width: -moz-calc(100% - 200px);
  width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.item .child-item1 .name,
.item .child-item1 .value {
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  display: block;
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.item .child-item1 .name {
  background-color: #ff0685;
}

.item .child-item1 .value {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
.item .child-item2 {
  border: 2px solid #eaeaea;
  width: 200px;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="item">
    <div class="child-item1">
        <div class="name">Lorem Ipsum is simply</div>
        <div class="value">value value value</div>
    </div>
    <div class="child-item2">
        label
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your solution shows just three simple columns. What I need is a kind of rowspan. Please see my question again.

Comment: This is based on your `html` code. You can add more column. `width` will be `auto` and `height` will be same `100%`.

Comment: That is unfortunately still not what I need. I have updated my example. Please see https://jsfiddle.net/qrrrv0jj/5/

Comment: I created new solution. You can try this.

Comment: The markup is unfortunately not kept in your solution. Please see my answer. Maybe you can help me with the positioning of the value element? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, I added the `.value` to the list with all the CSS for `.name` and `.label`. Then I changed the `heigth` and `width` of `.value` to `100%` and it worked.

The value `div` won't get bigger when there's more content inside and it's all nice and centered.

**PS:** Adding `overflow: hidden` to `.value` will keep the content from going outside the `div`.

[Update for your JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qrrrv0jj/1/)

Comment: Unfortunately not the right solution. Note that the first column should have an automatic width. See https://jsfiddle.net/qrrrv0jj/2/.

Comment: @Daniel Oh I see, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Ok, but 65% is not what I want. I need an automatic width for the first column. `column1.width = parentWidth - column2.width`. And the second colmun must not be wider than its content or max-width.